# Does X(13) have potentially good reduction at 13?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms

The complete level modular curve $X(p)$ does not have potentially good reduction at $p$ for any $p \neq 2,3,5,7,13$ because then there are cusp forms on $X_0(p)$ showing up in the cohomology of $X(p)$, whose associated Galois representations have unipotent local monodromy at $p$, which contradicts potentially good reduction.

$X(p)$ clearly does have good reduction at $p$ for $p=2,3,5$ because it has genus $0$ and a rational point.

$X(7)$ nonobviously has potential good reduction at $p=7$ where $X(7)$, the Klein quartic curve in $\mathbb P^2$, degenerates to a smooth hyperelliptic curve. See, for instance, [Elkies's paper on the Klein quartic](http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf).

So $p=13$ is the only remaining case. What's the answer there?

A good first step might be to try to answer the question for $X_1(13)$, which only has genus $2$.

Comment: The Jacobian $J(13)$ admits as a factor $J_0(169)^+$, which is a 3-dimensional variety isogenous to $A_f$, where $f \in S_2(\Gamma_0(169))^+$ is a newform with coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_7)^+$. Does this $A_f$ have potential good reduction at $13$?

Comment: The stable reduction of all $X(p)$ has been worked out by Bouw and Wewers in their paper "Stable reduction of modular curves". In particular, it also follows from their results that $X(13)$ does not have potentially good reduction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding Will's question on $X(13)$, it follows from Michael Stoll's answer and the following lemma that $X(13)$ does not have potentially good reduction.

Lemma. *Let $X\to Y$ be a finite morphism of smooth projective geometrically connected curves over a number field $K$. Suppose that $Y$ has non-zero genus. If $X$ has good reduction over $O_K$, then $Y$ has good reduction over $O_K$.*

**Proof.** This follows from the existence of Neron models for hyperbolic curves (not only abelian varieties); see Corollary 4.7 in Liu-Tong http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4822 . QED

One now concludes as follows. Suppose that $X(13)$ has good reduction everywhere over some number field $K$. Replacing $K$ by a finite field extension if necessary, there  is a (natural) finite morphism $X(13)\to X_1(13)$. Since  $X_1(13)$ has genus two, it follows from the above lemma  that $X_1(13)$ has good reduction over $O_K$. This contradicts Stoll's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Regarding Will's question on $X_1(13)$:

An equation of this genus 2 curve is
$$y^2 = x^6 - 2 x^5 + x^4 - 2 x^3 + 6 x^2 - 4 x + 1.$$
The polynomial on the right, when reduced mod 13, has a triple root at $-3$ and three simple roots. Over ${\mathbb Q}_{13}$, the roots reducing to $-3$ are of the form $-3+\theta_j$ with $v_{13}(\theta_j) = \frac{1}{3}$ and
$v_{13}(\theta_i - \theta_j) = \frac{1}{3}$ when $i \neq j$. This implies
that over a sufficiently ramified finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}_{13}$
(ramification index divisible by 6 is sufficient), the stable model
of $X_1(13)$ will have special fiber consisting of two elliptic curves
meeting transversally in one point (if my computation is correct,
then both curves have $j$-invariant zero). This in turn means that
the *curve* $X_1(13)$ has *bad* reduction over any extension of
${\mathbb Q}_{13}$, but its *Jacobian* $J_1(13)$ has *good* reduction
over sufficiently ramified extensions (its reduction is the product of
the two elliptic curves and hence an abelian variety). 
So this is a case of (potentially) "mildly bad reduction".

Comment: Indeed $J_1(13)$ has good reduction over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{13})$ (see my comment to @znt's answer). Actually over that number field $J_1(13)$ is isogenous to the product of two conjugate elliptic curves defined over $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{13})$. These elliptic curves have been determined in the article "Q-curves and their Manin ideals" by Josep González and Joan-C. Lario.

Answer (score 9):

If there were a newform which didn't have potentially good reduction and whose associated abelian variety were isogenous to a subvariety of $Jac(X(p))$ then the associated local automorphic representation would have to be a twist of the Steinberg. The character that one is twisting by would have to have conductor 1 or $p$ (otherwise the conductor of the local automorphic rep at $p$ would be bigger than $p^2$) and there's a global character which looks like this locally on inertia; untwisting by this global char shows that the twisted modular form contributes to the cohomology of $X_0(p)$. So if $X_0(p)$ has genus 0 then $Jac(X(p))$ has potentially good reduction at $p$. I don't think this quite proves that $X(p)$ has good reduction at $p$ but it answers François' question at least. The implicit claim in the question that $X_0(p)$ has good reduction at $p$ because it has genus 0 isn't quite a complete argument: twists of the projective line can have bad reduction at some primes, but Will is of course OK because $X_0(p)$ has cusps and hence points.

Comment: PS I'm new here -- how do I get the cedilla on Francois using a US keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. For the cedilla the simplest is copy&paste, but I'm not really sensible to it

Comment: On a mac I believe option+c does the trick.

Comment: @znt on a mac it actually works the same as with an ipad/iphone: press and hold a key and all the possible modifications of the letter will eventually be displayed for you to choose from

Comment: According to Katz-Mazur, Deligne and Rapoport showed that for $p$ prime, the abelian variety $J_1(p)/J_0(p)$ has good reduction over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$. I wonder what can be said about $J(p)/J_0(p)$.

Comment: In fact it has good reduction over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)^+$ (because the tame level is 1). There are two ways of thinking about this. First you can write down a semistable model for $X_1(p)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ and compare with $X_0(p)$ via a vanishing cycle computation as is done in KM. Alternatively you can invoke local Langlands and see that the forms contributing have level $p$ and non-trivial character so are principal series with one unramified and one tame character, to get the same result. Of course both approaches are "the same" in the sense that the *proof* of local-global...

Comment: goes precisely via this sort of construction. With $J(p)/J_0(p)$ the story is more complicated. For a start there will be tame quadratic twists of Steinberg forms (e.g. $J_0(p)$ itself) so it doesn't have pot good redn. And then you see some dihedral chars induced from chars of order $p^2-1$ so you need bigger tame extensions. Maybe there are more too, I don't carry the classification of low conductor supercuspidals around in my head :-/